# How do I calculate the phase difference between 2 waves based on the graph of the intensity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, superposition

[image]

For bii. I have tried to calculate the intensity by looking at the path difference between the waves to reach Point R but it does not seem to work. How else would I be able to determine the phase difference between the 2 waves based on the graph? Am I suppose to reference the peak intensity or the distance from the centre?

Answer (score 0):

If two waves are canceling each other out, then the peak of one matches the trough of the other. So they are $\phi = \pi$ phase shifted. Think about a sine curve. When they reinforce each other, they are in phase, $\phi =0$. R seems to be between those. At that peak between Q and R, where $d=-2.2 ~mm$, they are in phase, meaning $ 2 N \pi $ out of phase, $N=0,1,2..~$. So one traveled a whole wavelength further than the other.

Does that answer all?